# Import directory structure into eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I've recently gotten the source code to a jsp application (I'm primarily a c# guy, so apologies for any terminology that doesn't fit).   I'm trying to use Eclipse to make changes and run the application locally, but am having some problems getting started.

The folder structure is as follows

```
/Admin
/css
/js
/jsp
...more folders that look like your typical web site
/WEB-INF
  /classes
  /lib
  web.xml
  taglib-i18n.tld
build.xml
index.jsp
```

I've tried creating an empty dynamic web application and dragging the folders in, but there are ton's of build errors saying that the code found in the sub directories under `/classes/` isn't recognized.

I can run a very simple jsp tutorial locally, so I'm confident that tomcat and the jsp framework is installed.

The source code is coming straight from (sorry) Source Safe and the current methodology is to make changes and deploy and test on a development server.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing or need to configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are not telling Eclipse about your dependencies.  Go to Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries and make sure you have all your dependency JARs referenced there.